# How to add User to ClusterRoleBinding in Openshift Template

Tags: templates, jenkins, yaml, containers, openshift

I am new with OpenShift and creating templates. Now I want to write a template to create a new namespace with some user. One of my users (jenkins) should be added to cluster role system:controller:persistent-volume-binder.

Until now I am able to create a namespace and its corresponding policybindings and rolebindings.

Now I want to add "jenkins" to ClusterRole system:controller:persistent-volume-binder.

```
# CLUSTERROLEBINDING
  - apiVersion: v1
  groupNames: null
  kind: ClusterRoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: system:controller:persistent-volume-binder
  roleRef:
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: system:controller:persistent-volume-binder
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: jenkins
    namespace: ${NAMESPACE_NAME}
  userNames:
  - system:serviceaccount:${NAMESPACE_NAME}:jenkins
```

After processing and creating I get the following error message:

```
Error from server (AlreadyExists): clusterrolebinding.authorization.openshift.io "system:controller:persistent-volume-binder" already exists
```

Can somebody help, please?

Kind Regards, 
Sarah

Comment: What are you using to process is? Are you using ``oc edit``, ``oc create``, ``oc replace``, or ``oc apply``?

Comment: I am using `oc process -f namespace.yml --param-file=../openshift-params/namespace.env | oc create -f -`

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my template:

`objects:` was missing before apiVersion. Now it works with `oc apply`, because it is not possible to create an object which exists already. Because of this I had to cut this part out of my "namespace" template and create a new one for clusterrolebindings.

Kind Regards,
Sarah